# Need modal to be created only on the click of a cell in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, html-table, bootstrap-modal

I hope the title is not too confusing to you; I know I'd be confused if I read a title like that.

Anyway, on a serious note, I have the following code:

```
 <table>
 <thead>
 <tr>
 <td>Heading</td>
 </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 <tr>
 <td data-toggle="modal" data-target=".Table1">Table 1</td>
 <td>Table 2</td>
 </tbody>
 </table>
```

And now I have the following 2 modals: (to keep this post short and simple I will post the code for only one modal)

```
 <div class="modal Table1">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
 <div class="modal-content">
 <div class="modal-header">
 <button data-dissmiss="modal" class="close"><span>&times;</span></button>
 <div class="modal-title">Table 1</div>
 </div>
 <div class="modal-body">
 <table>
 <thead>
 <tr>
 <td>Table 1</td>
 </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 <tr>
 <td>ABC</td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Firstly, I'm using bootstrap and hence all the classes.

OK, so I need this modal (popup) to be generated only on click of the cell in the first table.

Now I know that this modal is hidden because of bootstrap, but that is exactly what I don't want. I do not want this modal to be created on page load even though it is hidden. It should be only created and displayed on click of the cell in the first table.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you should use ajax + php to create modal dynamic.
When your page has been executed initially your page will not have the modal body in the page. But yes the divs up to   should be there in the page. The body of the modal can be generated dynamically and bind in the popup. Please check below code.

```
<?php
    //PHP CODE
    if(isset($_POST['openModal'])){ 
        ob_start(); ?>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>Table 1</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>ABC</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <?php 
        echo json_encode(["HTML"=>ob_get_clean()]);
    }else{  ?>
        // HTML CODE
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

         <table>
             <thead>
                 <tr>
                    <td>Heading</td>
                 </tr>
             </thead>
             <tbody>
                 <tr>
                    <td data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Table 1</td>
                    <td>Table 2</td>
                 </tr>
             </tbody>
         </table>
         <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">

                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
         //Javascript + jquery code
         <script>
            $("td[data-target='#myModal']").on("click",function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url : 'abc.php',
                    data : "openModal=1",
                    type : 'post',
                    dataType : 'json',
                    success : function(data){
                        $(".modal-body").html(data.HTML);
                    }
                });
            });
         </script>
    <?php } ?>
```